# How to get the graph resource name for a node?

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
**After** launching a node, I can get its graph resource name using the `rosnode info /node_name` command line.
Is there a way to get this information **Before** launching the node?

As an example, suppose that I want info about turtlesim_node.  Currently, I have first to run it
`rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node`

Then I have to find out some how what is the name of the node I'm interested in, for example by using:
`rosnode list`
This will show me all running nodes. Knowing the previous list of running nodes, I can deduce that the new node is named `/turtlesim`. This way of doing it already annoys me. Is there a simpler way?

And once I have found the node name, I have still to use the rosnode command to have topics published and subscribed by my node
`rosnode info /turtlesim`
Again, this is heavy.

I wonder if I can have the names directly from the  turtlesim package without launching turtlesim_node?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62812/how-to-get-the-graph-resource-name-for-a-node?/) by [Noury](https://answers.ros.org/users/2533/noury/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-05-15**:
Can you clarify what information you want? It seems that you already have the node name.

**Comment by [Noury](https://answers.ros.org/users/2533/noury/) on 2013-05-23**:
I updated the question and provided an example. I can sum up the question as: Is there a way to find out the default node name and topic names before launching the node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not a way to statically determine what the name of a node is programmed to be.  However, you can set the node name on the command line using the [command line remapping arguments](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Nodes#Command-line_Remapping_Arguments).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1